# My laptop boots to blank screen on Ubuntu 16.04 until I remove the battery twice

Tags: boot, battery

Every time I turn on my laptop, at the first attempt it boots to a black screen. I then remove the battery, and on the second attempt the laptop produces the Ubuntu login sound but no display. I again remove my battery, and only on the third attempt does the screen boot to login screen.

Comment: Have you checked with external monitor?

Comment: Please mention your laptop model and graphics card details if you have any.

Comment: how to find laptop model im new to ubuntu i dont know any commands

Comment: Do you see ubuntu splash screen (ubuntu logo with progress dots below it) before it goes black?

Comment: ya sometimes but many times i cant

Comment: Somewhere your laptop model will be mentioned. Check back side and in some of the models it will be pasted under the battery.

Comment: whether there was any option find using terminal

Comment: HP Pavilion 15-AB125AX Notebook A10-8700P/8GB/1TB/Win10/2GB Grap (P6M13PA#ACJ) this was the model of my laptop

Answer (score 0):

This intermittent black screen problem is bizarre. I had this for a long time and it went away after I did the following actions. Keep in mind that it can a problem in Ubuntu specific to your device, so this might not fix that. In that case you might want to revert the changes I make, instructions to do that are given in the end of answer.

**Log in somehow:** If you have managed to log in by  battery quirks then proceed to next step. Otherwise get a `GRUB` [menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) during boot, select the option with `recovery mode` (use down/up key to move selection) and press enter. This should not end in black screen. If it does, then I'm clueless.

**Main actions:** Once you have somehow logged into Ubuntu:

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to start a terminal.
2. Backup `/etc/default/grub`, copy it to you home folder. Run:

   ```
   cp /etc/default/grub ~
   ```
3. Disable splash screen and enable log messages during boot:

   ```
   sudo sed -i '/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT/{s/splash//;s/quiet//}' /etc/default/grub
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot
   and boot normally (no in recovery mode)

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

**Revert to Old Settings:** *If the system reboots fine, then do your stuff and ignore this.* If the problem continues and you want to revert to original settings. Then, login somehow, and run in terminal:

```
sudo cp ~/grub /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: As a sidenote: this is most likely not a solution (nor an answer) but nevertheless a good hint how to make the boot-process more verbose.

Comment: when i tried to copy it shows error permission denid

Comment: thanks a lot bro its worked for me am i also facing a another problem it takes a lot of time to boot and get into login screen and it also have some performance lag on startup how to boost it and again thanks in advance

Comment: @dufte I think Ubuntu fumbles with kernel mode setting specifically when it tries to show splash screen. This is what I figure from my experience. I struggled for months and even went down exploring ways to fix UEFI firmware. Ubuntu still lost hold of screen backlight after boot, just before login screen is shown. I took the steps mentioned in this answer and noticfed that it never booted to black screen after that. I could successfully reproduce the problem by reverting changes. I was all for losing the splash screen and boot up quietness to get rid of that black screen. So I did.

Comment: @joshua have you tried rebooting a few times? is it sluggish every time?

Comment: ya the above step only some times again it started to becoming black

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, Ubuntu cannot cannot recognize if your built-in screen is present or not. It generally happen with AMD Chipset laptop.

My laptop used to have this problem. You can fix this in the System Setting.

Setting > Color > Laptop Screen

If you see Laptop Screen **Not Calibrated**, then click on **Add Profile**.
[image: Laptop Screen - Not Calibrated]

Select **Default: Your Laptop Model** *(eg: my laptop **Default: Gateway 4250s**)* then click **Add**.
[image: Add Profile - Select Profile - Add]

Then click on **Set for all user**.

Then Reboot. I expect it will boot up normally.